# Building a Python Django model with multiple images

Tags: python, django, database, database-design

I have the following models in Django:

```
class SpaCenter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    house_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    house_number = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class SpaCenterImages(models.Model):
    spacenter = models.ForeignKey(SpaCenter)
    image = models.ImageField()
    primary_image = models.BooleanField()

class SpaCenterWebsites(models.Model):
    spacenter = models.ForeignKey(SpaCenter)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

PART 1:

I would like:
1) the "SpaCenter" model to have multiple images belonging to it, and 2) One of those images to be selectable as the "primary" image.

Whats the best way to go about building a django model for that? I think I got (1) right...but overall would like to hear some advice on model design.

Basically the same principle as Facebook - 1 profile can have multiple images.

PART 2:

How would one go about scripting the Django admin console for these models in order to allow for multiple images to be uploaded against one profile.

---

I am quite new to Django, so help is very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented similar functionality as yours before. To me it's not so clear how to restrict one `primary_image` for `SpaCenter` in the model level, but your model design seems to be enough to achieve what you want.

What you can do is to use django formset to make sure there's only one primary exists. Here's a rough idea(not tested):

```
class SpaCenterImageFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):                                                                                                                                                                 

    def clean(self):                                                                                                                                                                                    
        super(SpaCenterImageFormSet, self).clean()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        primary_count = 0                                                                                                                                                                                          

        for form in self.forms:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            if 'primary_image' in form.cleaned_data and \
               form.cleaned_data['primary_image']:                                                                                                                              
                primary_count += 1                                                                                                                                                                                 

        if self.forms and primary_count == 0:                                                                                                                                                                      
            raise ValidationError("You must have one primary image!")                                                                                                                      
        if primary_count > 1:                                                                                                                                                                                      
            raise ValidationError("You cannot have more than one primary image!")
```

One last thing, don't use plural form in model names, django will add it for you when needed, or you can customize it yourself.

For your part 2 of the question, use normal admin for `SpaCenter` and `Inline` for `SpaCenterImage` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects